# How to log to tensorboard from ray.tune when using the class API?

Tags: ray

None of the examples in the docs show how logging happens with the class api? Do you still use `tune.track.log` even in the class api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logging to tensorflow should happen automatically when using the class API - I'll update the docs to make this more clear.